# extracting multiple tar files in folders with their corresponding file names

Tags: linux, tar, for

**Hi I'm having a multiple tar files like 1.tar 2.tar 3.tar..etc and i wanted to extract them to corresponding folders i.e 1.tar to a folder named 1 and so on...
my trial was like the following:**

```
   for f in *; do
   tar -xvf "$f.tar" --xform='s|^|$f/|S';
   done
```

**which doesn't work as expected
how can i achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

**I got it working like that :**

```
for t in *.tar ; do
  bn="$(basename -- "$t" .tar)"
  mkdir -p -- "$bn" &&
    tar -xf "$t" -C "$bn"
done
```

**which did exactly what I want**

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for two reasons:

1. you use the `--transform` expression inside single quotes so expansion is disabled.
2. the way you use the glob is wrong `for f in *; do tar -xvf "$f.tar"...` means `*` matches the whole file name e.g. `1.tar` so `$f.tar` is expanded to `1.tar.tar` which most likely results in  an error like `No such file or directory`

Try something like:

```
for f in *.tar
do
tar -tf  "$f" --xform="s|^|${f%.*}/|S" --show-transformed-names
done
```

if you're happy with the output replace the dry-run command with

```
tar -xf  "$f" --xform="s|^|${f%.*}/|S"
```

although in this particular case you could simply run

```
for f in *.tar; do tar -xf "$f" --one-top-level; done
```

Answer (score 0):

`--xform` / `--transform` is a GNU extension. Some `tar` implementations have `-s` for that (same as in standard `pax`).

Here, with GNU `tar`, instead of `--xform`, you can use `--one-top-level` which is designed for that:

```
for f in *.tar; do
  tar --one-top-level="${f%.tar}" -xf "$tar"
done
```

(assuming there's at least one non-hidden file whose name ends in `.tar` in the current directory), or with `zsh`:

```
for f (*.tar(N)) tar --one-top-level=$f:r -xf $f
```